# Suggestions on Turtlebot- Create or Roomba?

Tags: ros, roomba, turtlebot, create, stereo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Dear All,

I will soon be entering into my PhD studies and would like to work with ROS vision libraries for SLAM. I am really interested in turtlebot since its low cost and efficient enough for using vision systems and doing SLAM. My question is, which is better for turtlebot, i am in japan. Create or roomba? I can get create with little efforts here in Japan. Also if in future I want to use a stereo camera to my Turtlebot wil that be possible.
I heard turtlebot with Roomba is little tricky to get start with. I am new to ROS and need something which gives me a good head start.
So icreate or roomba and why?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/44399/suggestions-on-turtlebot--create-or-roomba?/) by [Vegeta](https://answers.ros.org/users/2476/vegeta/) on ROS Answers with karma: 340 on 2012-09-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Create is a better option for the TurtleBot. If you opt for Roomba you may have to tweak the parts to fit it. Since you say that you are just starting with ROS and TurtleBot, do not waste time with Roomba. I suggest you to buy a standard TurtleBot to start off with. You have lots of cool apps for it in ROS and well laid tutorials to keep you advancing. I worked on the TurtleBot with create and found it perfect (never worked with roomba though). And also, you can add a [stereo camera in future to your TurtleBot](http://sluggish.dyndns.org/images/5/53/Turtlebot_28_07_2012a.jpg). So, go for Create! Wish you good luck!

---

Originally posted by [prasanna.kumar](https://answers.ros.org/users/2416/prasanna.kumar/) with karma: 1363 on 2012-09-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dejanpan](https://answers.ros.org/users/92/dejanpan/) on 2012-09-23**:
Some more insightful info also here: http://ros-users.122217.n3.nabble.com/iRobot-Roomba-vs-Create-td2019380.html.